# Except Operator T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Task: Display c_id and c_name for customers who have at least 1 purchase in any 2 of the months but not in all 3 months.

```
First Month = November
Second Month = December
Third Month = January



SELECT c_id, c_name
FROM books
WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 11
INTERSECT
SELECT c_id, c_name 
FROM books
WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 12
EXCEPT
SELECT c_id, c_name
FROM books
WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 1
```

The current code I have negates the 3rd month but it doesn't fulfill what the task is asking which is to select any 2 months interchangeably.

Rule is: No count, No Subquery, No Join(s)

Comment: Why not just use group by based on the month and then having count = 2 and not 3?

Comment: sorry about that. I forgot to include that there's no use of count/subquery/join(s)

Comment: Idle curiosity - is this one of those contrived problems to teach you the features, or an actual scenario you are facing, with the said conditions?

Comment: Yep! She wants us to understand the different features of T-SQL by strictly using only those features.

Comment: Ah, figured as much. Do let me know if my answer helped, or if you are looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with this.

```
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 1
intersect 
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 11
union
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 1
intersect 
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 12
union
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 12
intersect 
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 11
except
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 1
intersect 
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 11
intersect 
select c_id,c_name from books where month(order_date) = 12
```

This is equivalent to the expression:

`(Set A intersect Set B) union (Set A intersect Set C) union (Set C intersect Set B) minus (Set A intersect Set B intersect Set C)`,

or as you can see in the [image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/ABC_Venn_Diagram.svg), the regions AB, AC and BC

This is certainly not elegant, but given the requirements, it seems like brute force is a valid approach.

Comment: the drawing is AWESOME! i didn't quite fully understand the 'except' part but the drawing really hit it home. Thank you!!!